# POST and GET requests in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm a student and my university has site. There i can check my schedule. Now i learn Qt and for practise i try to write program that will show me schedule for today. If i do this request

```
QUrl url("http://msiu.ru/students/schedule/v3/#121332");
QNetworkRequest request(url);
```

then i just get a template of page (i mean there is no lessons for today). I think i have to use GET request to page to get all data i need. But i dont know how. I tried to use

```
QUrl params;
params.addQueryItem("ngroup", "121332");
```

but there was no results (I used Wireshark to see the GET request to site). So help me to get correct schedule. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website uses javascript to pull its data and format it for display. You'd need to examine the structure of the page in the developer console of a web browser to figure out what request to issue to get this data. You can also use wireshark, but perform the action from a clean web browser session (e.g. in privacy mode).

Alternatively, use `QWebPage` and retrieve the data from the DOM tree after the site has finished loading.

Comment: Ok, i got function for getting schedule (getGroup()). And there is a line:

.get("schedule.ajax.php", { ngroup: formVal }

So shoudl i use something like 
http://msiu.ru/students/schedule/v3/schedule.ajax.php?ngroup=121332?